# Store the output of Subprocess.call in a String

Tags: python, unix, subprocess

I am trying to hit a unix command through python code.But when I am using the subprocess.call function it is directly poping the result.
I want to store that result into a string.
Below is my code sample.

```
import subprocess
Store_result=subprocess.call("grep 'xyz-pqr' textfile_5906.txt",shell=True)
print Store_result
```

**#This returns me 0**

I want to store the result in one string and use it for further coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x=subprocess.Popen("grep 'xyz-pqr' textfile_5906.txt",shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
output,err=x.communicate()
```

This way you can have error and output.